# "Вопрос к..." Какой тип предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Идет некая конференция. Журналист задает вопрос:

> «Газета Ведомости. Вопрос к Сергею. Почему Вы считаете, что…»

***Вопрос к Сергею*** – это какая синтаксическая конструкция?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Вопрос к Сергею.***

Другими словами: Этот вопрос адресован Сергею, предназначен для Сергея.

Поэтому я считаю, что это не назывное предложение, а **двусоставное эллиптическое** вида "подлежащее ― дополнение".  Сказуемое в таких предложениях отсутствует, но подразумевается.